# auto-sizing a textview?

Tags: android, textview, autosize

I want to auto size a text view. I have the min and max size for text and the max height for the textview. I dont want to set a specific height for the text view. I am doing as below but its not working. It gives max height as text view height. How can it make the height to adjust as per the text

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/title"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/title_text_height"
                                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
                                app:layout_constraintWidth_max="480dp"
                                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:text="@{title}"
                                android:textAlignment="center"

                                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/title_text_max_size"
                                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/title_text_min_size"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date"
                                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left_margin_24"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_margin_24"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_top_or_bottom"
                                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                                tools:text="testvtest"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/17782522#17782522

Comment: @png I have added my code please review.It may be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code it may be helpful to solve your issue.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wrap content not match parent